# Javascript setInterval - how to set a good timing & performance

Tags: javascript, performance, setinterval

I'm writing a simple jquery plugin that let me add classes to elements at a certain scroll position. To accomplish this, rather than binding **onScroll** events, I call a setInterval function that checks the current Y page offset:

`interval = window.setInterval(update, 25);`

How you can see, I set the interval at 25 ms. I was wondering if this is to be considered a right time, and how the performance are effectively involved.

Comment: Why are you not using onscroll events? I only ask because I would avoid polling if at all possible.

Comment: you should remove the parenthesis form the first argument to setTimeout

Answer (score 3):

For performance while animating, it's better to use '`requestAnimationFrame`'. This way, the browser won't be updating all the time while the tab isn't active + it might do some additional optimizations.

`requestAnimationFrame` isn't supported yet by most browsers but - of course - Paul Irish has a nifty polyfill ready: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: One thing I'd like to discover is how you'd go about clear interval events set with requestAnimationFrame, have you had any experience with this

Comment: Isn't there webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame ? 

http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/#comment-47068

Answer (score 2):

i think performance wise you better should be going with something like the code below, this way you are sure that the update function only gets triggered when running update function has finished.

```
function update() {
  //do stuff
  setTimer(); 
}

function setTimer() {
  timeout = window.setTimeout(update(), 25);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `timeout = window.setTimeout(update, 25);`